# Way to listen in on all Apple Events?

Tags: cocoa, macos, applescript, macos-carbon, appleevents

I'm looking for a way to listen in to all Apple Events send by any program to any other program. There was an app, AEMonitor, that used to do this but it is abandonware as of now.

Is there a known way to do this via cocoa, carbon, etc?

Any help MUCH appreciated.

--

Target OS is 10.6

--

**Carification:** I'm looking to monitor ALL apple events or at very least a lion share of them. I am aware that it is possible to launch an app and listen to its AEs [like this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030430145833233&query=terminal).

Comment: Is `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` what you want?  I guess that's distributed notifications, not Apple Events (or are they the same thing?)

Comment: No - that's for NSDistributedNotifications. A great tool for monitoring those is "Notification Watcher" http://github.com/kballard/NotificationWatcher

Comment: Distributed notifications and Apple Events have nothing to do with each other. An Apple Event goes to a specific application (the event's target); a distributed notification is sent to all applications in the same login session.

Comment: Does this imply that the directionality of Apple Events makes them un-monitorable by a third party app? (without first enabling AEDebug before launching the third party app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I recall of AEMonitor (which I occasionally miss), it required the relaunch of the target application.  I'd bet that it was setting the environment variables that are linked to in the macosxhints.com article.

Comment: Argh. That's disappointing. I suppose this means that the answer to my question is No.

Comment: Perhaps is there any way to boot OSX such that every app would have AEDebug enabled?

Comment: Could you not make a script to go through every application in your OS X install and replace the app with a script that would launch the app via the terminal after setting AEDebug? http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080809181956219 Then you could launch any app, it'd autoenable AEDebug from the script before launching, then Bob would indeed be your uncle. Theoretically...

Comment: Andrew, John Gallagher: You can set up your environment.plist to contain the requisite environment variables for your next log-in. I wouldn't, though—the output would be way too noisy. You might even bog down syslogd, depending on just how much Apple Events are used behind the scenes. And even if you find that useful, it's only for debugging—this would be absolutely terrible to do to the user from a software program.

Comment: this is for as a dev tool, not for actual release of software.